# Wordpress - Gravity Forms shortcode not working without url parameter present

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms, wordpress-shortcode

I have some forms that will display based on a various conditions (post ID, unix time, etc). They're in the template file like so:
`echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="10" title="false" description="false"]');`

When I load the page the form doesn't render and just the shortcode itself is displayed. However, if I add any parameter to the url it works as expected. I can literally add any made up parameter and it works.

I'm not getting any errors so it's a little difficult to debug. Anyone have any idea why this is happening or has experienced this before?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: @Rochelle yeah, multiple times. It's not the first time it's happened on this site either, on existing and newly created pages.

Comment: It may be some kind of plugin conflict but I would also see if it's a caching problem with your host.  I've had weird issues like that where the only thing that worked was clearing the cache from the host site itself...That can usually be done from the host's dashboard.  If that works, you can try changing your overall cache settings on the site.

Comment: @Rochelle I cleared it on the server side multiple times and it's not local either because I've cleared that, used an incognito window, and had other people test it. It's the weirdest thing. Any parameter works, ex: ?madeup=value The site wasn't built by me and it's a mess, so I'm sure it's just some sort of conflict at this point